# Display the cookies values in the same page php-cookies

Tags: php

I have text box and submit button.
I write something in the text box and set a cookies for the text box values on sumbit.
And put the form action to the same page and display the cookies information.
The problem is that without refreshing the page,the cookies values is not being displayed or 
before refreshing,it display the previous cookies value.

Comment: Does the *on submit* part mean you are setting them with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

After setting cookie you have to redirect on the same page.

> Once the cookies have been set, they
>   can be accessed on the next page load
>   with the $_COOKIE

so you have to make a redirection on same page.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    setcookie("TestCookie", 'shakti', time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
    header('location:test.php');die();
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Comment: Nope, you are doing something wrong check the code posted I tested it working fine

Comment: hi need the current cookies in the text box

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

taken from [Sitepoint](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/caching-php-performance), this is just an option. Can you post code...